# Как записать условие несовпадения количества цифр в шестнадцатеричной и десятичной записях

Tags: python

**Количество цифр в шестнадцатеричной и десятичной записях числа не совпадает.**
Вот само задание :
Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [1871; 9197], которые удовлетворяют следующим условиям:
− количество цифр в шестнадцатеричной и десятичной записях числа не совпадает;
− остаток от деления на 9 равен 2 или 4.
Найдите количество таких чисел и минимальное из них.

```
a=[]

for i in range(1871, 9198):
    if (len(hex(i)[2:]) != len(str(i)) and (i%9 == 2 or i%9 == 4)):
        a.append(i)

print(len(a),(min(a)))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Например, так: `len(hex(n)[2:]) != len(str(n))` или так: `len(f'{n:x}') != len(f'{n:d}')`

Comment: Не нужно условия записывать, если они для проверки. Просто надо покумекать, в каком реальном диапазоне лежат эти числа, и тогда легко найти, сколько их, без перебора.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо, у меня в пичарме был выбран не карент файл......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=[]
for i in range(1871, 9198):
    if (len(hex(i)[2:]) != len(str(i)) and (i%9 == 2 or i%9 == 4)):
        a.append(i)
print(len(a),(min(a)))
#Спасибо CrazyElf
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного оптимизировал код за счет сужения диапазона, исключения проверок на длину чисел и сокращение операций нахождения остатка + сэкономил память на списке

```
diap = 1871, 9198  # десятичных цифр всегда 4 в этом диапазоне
amount, min_n, rest = 0, None, {2, 4}  # вместо списка заводим переменные, где будут кол-во чисел и минимум
for i in range(diap[0], min(diap[1], 16 ** 3)):  # ограничиваем диапазон сверху, чтобы не проверять кол-во цифр
    if i % 9 in rest:  # чтобы не находить дважды остаток от деления
        amount += 1
        if min_n is None:
            min_n = i  # поскольку диапазон возрастает, то для минимума достаточно взять первое подходящее число
print(f'Кол-во: {amount}, минимальное: {min_n}')
```

```
Кол-во: 494, минимальное: 1874
```

Comment: Ради двух переменных заводить словарь несколько странновато ))

Comment: @CrazyElf В целом согласен, на словарь больше ресурсов тратится, чем на 2 переменные. Зато печатает сразу красиво :)